# Problem with posting distance relationship data of an authenticated user in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-query-builder

I have three models as per the code below. I have a problem of posting client data who is a user within the system and should be authenticated.I am thing of something like this:

```
 public function store_application(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new LoanApplication();
        $data->client_id = $client->id;
     
        $data->save();
       
    }
```

**Loan Application Model**

```
class LoanApplication extends Model
   
     {
           
          public function client()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');
        }
        
        }
```

**Client Model**

```
class Client extends Model
    {
       
        public function client_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientUser::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }
    
    }
```

**Client User Model**

```
class ClientUser extends Model
    {
       
    public function user()
       {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
        }
    
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the answer to the above question:
public function store_application(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $client= ClientUser::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('client_id');
        $data = new LoanApplication();
        $data->$client;
        $data->save();
       
    }
```